# PHP: Namespace resolution in object method chains

Tags: php, namespaces, chaining, method-chaining

We use method chaining in several of our core systems. We're trying to namespace some of those systems away from our modules. However I'm having trouble getting any kind of namespace resolution with chaining to work.

So while this works (as usual):

```
$GLOBALS['model']->User()->User_Friends()->getAll();
```

this, on the other hand:

```
$GLOBALS['model']->Core\User()->User_Friends()->getAll();
```

throws the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR
```

Is there any way around this?

I'm almost already assuming this is a no-go. But asking to make sure I'm not missing something.

Depending on your point-of-view (definitely mine), it is a bug.

Comment: You can namespace a class, or a function, but not a method.

Comment: Seems you're also trying too hard with namespacing everything. Why would you need attributes/methods to be grouped like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution of the namespace can occur **within** the method `User`, not as a property **of** the method itself.

In code:

```
class model {
  private $user = false;
  public function User () {
    if ($this->user == false)
       $this->user = new Core\User(); // <--- namespace use happens here
    return $this->user;
  }
}
```

Thus, the return of the method `User` is the `User` class from the namespace `Core`, of which the method `User_Friends()` is a part.

**EDIT**
I suggest you take another look at the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) as well as the "[Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)" article.

**EDIT 2**
Using `__NAMESPACE__` to determine which namespace to operate in, from within an overloaded method:

```
class model {
    private $objects = array();
    public function __call($name, $arguments=false) {
        $ns = __NAMESPACE__;
        if (strlen($ns) < 1)
            $ns = 'none';
        if (!isset($this->objects[$ns]))
            $this->objects[$ns] = array();
        if (!isset($this->objects[$ns][$name])) {
            $class_desc = (strlen($ns) > 0 ? __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' : ''). $name;
            $this->objects[$ns][$name] = new $class_desc($arguments);
        }
        return $this->objects[$ns][$name];
    }
}
```

Comment: This cannot happen because the method user does not exist. A __call() method is handling that as fallback, and routing.

Comment: Then the namespace code used above would be used in the overload `__call` method. Bottom line - one does not namespace methods of a class. The class may have polymorphism within it that takes advantage of namespaces in a dynamic way, but the method itself is not aware of namespaces. The code I used above is to demonstrate the concept, not the literal solution.

Comment: Then you need to do use naming convention like `->Core_User()` and substitute `_` with `\\` in `__call()`

Comment: @Chris Yes, I understand. Sadly the overload method cannot make assumptions about the namespace.

Comment: @Mchl That is one of the only viable ideas. Unfortunately, we use underscores in our method names, so it is not a viable delimiter.

Comment: Would it be viable for the overload method to detect the current namespace? `$a = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $classname; return new $a;` That way, the overloader is not making any assumptions, and the caller has total control by simply switching namespaces before accessing `model`

Comment: @Chris I think there is some misunderstanding, because my example was bad. Another would be that we use `$GLOBALS['single']->MyClass()->myMethod();` .. this is obviously a singleton implementation, and because it can be _ANY_ class, `__NAMESPACE__` will not work because it will return the namespace that Singleton is sitting in. Unless I am misunderstanding what you are suggesting. So the namespace path needs to be provided at point of call, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have any sense. `GLOBALS['model']` is an object (I assume, since you're accessing its members using `->`) and object members can not be (and need not be) namespaced (since they belong to a specific class/object).

Since you're using `_call()` to magically invoke nonexisting methods, you need to assume a naving convention like for example `$GLOBALS['model']->Core_User()->User_Friends()->getAll();` and then in your `__call()` substitute `_` with `\`